# Is it right that combine 2 css framework

Tags: reactjs, frontend, css-frameworks

I have a project with react that I've developed that with Ant design . now I want to use Tailwind or Bootstrap with it . it's right to do? ,what do you suggest to do?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to combine multiple css framework but results can be conflicting due to same classes with different definitions.

Example: I added tailwind in ionic and started using ion-tags with combination of tailwind classes which many times didn't work as frameworks css overriding the classes most of the time, hence this could be conflicting sometimes.

Comment: OK, but Ant design ' s classes started with "ant" most of them and I think it won't be  problem in conflict because in Ant design  the classes start with ant

Comment: yes that can be the case but still it depends on the framework which you are using, In case of ionic - ion tags have some native classes so override external classes most of the time, ant design's classes is applicable to all, that is true!